# Why don't I find ping process in ps list?

Tags: ps, ping, setuid

Why can't I see the 'ping' process in my 'ps' listing when I started it as a regular user?

The ping binary has setuid bit,

```
 ls -l /bin/ping
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 64424 jun 28  2019 /bin/ping
```

Running ping in the background,

```
ping google.com > /dev/null &
[1] 28193
```

When I look for this process using ps as my user(enn) I don't find it,

```
 ps -ef  | grep 28193
```

Whereas if I use superuser, I can find it,

```
sudo ps -ef | grep 28193 | grep -v grep
enn  28193  6878  0 13:49 pts/3    00:00:00 ping google.com
```

Using **ps** to print the associated IDs and I could see the ping process is running with my {u,e,r}id/{g,e,r}id = 66973, 64000

The only difference I could see is in the **suid**, which is set to 0

```
sudo ps -e -o pid,uid,gid,euid,egid,ruid,rgid,suid,sgid,cmd | grep 28193 | grep -v grep

28193 66973 64000 66973 64000 66973 64000     0 64000 ping google.com
```

I am not able to understand the reason for this, Could someone help me understand what I can't see the process as a regular user?

**System Info**: "Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS"

Thanks in advance, Naga

Comment: probably some cgroup shitfuckery (because ping needs root privilege). I can't answer, but that's my guess.

Answer (score 1):

Works just fine here (Fedora 34). Run `ping 8.8.8.8` on one tab of my Gnome terminal, on another:

```
$ pgrep ping
295323
$ ps -ef | grep 295323 
user  295323    3772  0 18:50 pts/4    00:00:00 ping 8.8.8.8
user  295628    3726  0 18:53 pts/3    00:00:00 grep --color=auto 295323
```

Are you sure you didn't copy the PID wrong (happens to me around half of the time)? Is `ping` still running (it stops dead if it doesn't find the target, for example)?